# Algorithm that returns j'th smallest element from two sets

Tags: algorithm, set, divide-and-conquer

I have an assignment asking that from two sets M and N of equal size *j* holding distinct numbers, with access only to the functions kthsmallestM(int k) and kthsmallestN(int k), which return the k'th smallest integer from M and N respectively, the algorithm should find the *j*'th smallest element from M+N.

The way to do this using brute force is rather obvious, but the algorithm should run with O(log *j*) calls to kthsmallestM or kthsmallestN. I'm not looking for a complete solution, but I've been stuck on this for a while, so just some pointers to get me started would be appreciated!

**What I've tried:**
Checking if the largest element of M is smaller than the smallest element of N and vice versa, in which case, the answer would simply be the largest element of M or N, depending on the situation. I tried using that to make a recursive algorithm that performs the same check for smaller elements of both sets, but that quickly turns into O(n).

Any tips?

Comment: Take a look at the *selection algorithm*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *k* smallest elements will include some number *x* of the smallest from *M*, and the *k-x* smallest from *N*.

If we make a guess about *x*, then we can use *kthsmallestM(x)*, *kthsmallestN(k-x)*, *kthsmallestM(x+1)* and *kthsmallextN(k+1-x)*, to see whether our guess is too low, too high, or just right.

That means we can do a binary search to find the right value of *x* from 0 to *j*.